# Assembly and ResourceName not valid?

Tags: c#, reflection, resources, assemblies

I have this Code:

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();                 
foreach (string resourceName in myAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
    ManifestResourceInfo info = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(resourceName);
}
```

Why is **info** always **null** ? I have 7 ResourceFiles (.resx) and the *resourceName* of one of them looks like that:

```
"SchemaDifferenceFinder.Model.SQLStatements.MissingTriggers.resources"
```

Whats wrong, or does the resourceName must be something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assem = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("TestLibrary");   
System.Resources.ResourceManager rman = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("TestLibrary.Properties.Resources", assem);   
String s = rman.GetString("String1");
```

you need to create resourcemanager and than get access to data of resource

**Edit**

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();  
foreach (var resourceName in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())     
                System.Console.WriteLine(resourceName);
```

Comment: I'l try this, at least I only need the FileName, in my example I would do then: info.FileName, but its not possible, cause its always null

Comment: In your Example, s is also null :(

Comment: Your Edit works, and this always worked, but I don't need to do that, I need the FileName of the specified Resource